# Table rows inside a card body are not sized correctly in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a card in which under card body, I am displaying a table. One of the td contains a progress bar. However, this specific column containing the progress bar is not appearing of desired width (col-xs-8). I tried to set this on table headers and on specific data columns in tbody but this was of no avail. Any suggestions?

Working code snippet : https://www.codeply.com/go/2CGGezuq6j

Comment: I think they removed xs, just do `.col-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of bootstrap 4, you can't use xs, replace `col-xs-8` with just `col-8`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

**Edit:**

And remember to enclose your columns with the row class

Comment: Updated to col- but does not help. https://www.codeply.com/go/BGnAi3HaLt

Comment: you've changed back to bootstrap 3

Comment: if this helped you please marked it as answered

Comment: I am sorry for the oversight of including bootstrap 3. Updated with no luck at https://www.codeply.com/go/gm4g0JxaOA

Comment: you have to add `class="row"` to your `tr's` and you got one to many columns in your last table row